# Woo commerce only 1 item purchase

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have implemented the following code in my woo commerce site in the functions.php of my theme, however, when adding it, my site goes blank. Any ideas why? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
    function check_if_cart_has_product( $valid, $product_id, $quantity ) {  

    if(!empty(WC()->cart->get_cart()) && $valid){
        foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {
            $_product = $values['data'];

            if( $product_id == $_product->id ) {
                unset(WC()->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $valid;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_if_cart_has_product', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: can you `print_r(WC()->cart->get_cart());` ?

Comment: Blank pages imply a PHP error. You should enable WP Debug.

Comment: Definitely start with debugging. I'm not entirely sure what you are attempting to do as your title tells me one thing but then your code seems to be doing something else. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: I went with this instead: add_filter ( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'allow_single_quantity_in_cart' );
    function allow_single_quantity_in_cart() {
            global $woocommerce;

            $cart_contents  =  $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
            $keys           =  array_keys ( $cart_contents );

            foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
                    $woocommerce->cart->set_quantity ( $key, 1, true );
            }
    }

Answer (score 0):

To access the cart use:

```
    gloabl $woocommerce;  
    $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
```

Here is the available methods for that class:
http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html

Also read:
Debug in WP
https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG